# How to show info marker google maps when clicked in outside map?

Tags: javascript, jsp, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have problem to display info of google maps, when click in outside of map. but if inside of map when i click a marker, info of google maps can display.

```
function onload() {
    var st=getURLParameters("man");
    var kd_link=getURLParameters("kd");

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  var dt="";


xmlhttp.open("GET","hasil.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 


  var tbl=xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('page');

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 15,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-7.8711188835883945, 112.52471923828125),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP //ROADMAP //HYBRID 

});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var gmarkers=[];
var marker, i;

  function Linkclicked(i) {
    GEvent.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
  }

var kde;var nm;var l1;var l2;var bk;
for (i = 0; i < tbl.length; i++) {  

kde=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("kode")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
nm=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("nama")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
l1=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("lat")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
l2=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("long")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
bk=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("bk")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue; 

   marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(l1, l2),animation:an, icon:bk,map: map
  });

   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',(function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("nama")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

      infowindow.open(map, marker);
                       }
  })(marker, i));

    gmarkers[i]=marker;

}
}
```

that's my code, when i try to call one of the google maps info marker .

```
<a href="javascript:Linkclicked('0')">try</a>
```

it couldn't be displayed... please give me solution??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't call the LinkClicked function from your link, because you defined the function in the onload function.

if you use in your chrome browser the javascript console or in firefox browser with the firebug plugin also the console, you will see an error that LinkClicked is not defined,

so if you change your code that this function is general and also the gmarkers then it will work,

your code have to look like this:

```
var gmarkers = [];

function Linkclicked(i) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}

function onload() {
    var st = getURLParameters("man");
    var kd_link = getURLParameters("kd");

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    var dt = "";


    xmlhttp.open("GET", "return.xml", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;


    var tbl = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('page');

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-7.8711188835883945, 112.52471923828125),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP //ROADMAP //HYBRID 

    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;

    var kde;
    var nm;
    var l1;
    var l2;
    var bk;
    for (i = 0; i < tbl.length; i++) {

        kde = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("kode")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        nm = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("nama")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        l1 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("lat")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        l2 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("long")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        bk = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("bk")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(l1, l2),
            animation: an,
            icon: bk,
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("nama")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        gmarkers[i] = marker;

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still newbie at javascript program :D. I'm  vb.net programmer. yes thats true, thanks. @fmt.Println.MKO

Answer (score 0):

From your code `Linkclicked('0')` it looks like you are passing a string as argument. Inside the `Linkclicked() {}` definition you are trying to access gmarkers[i], and I don't think gmarkers index is a string. I think that is the reason why its not working.

Another thing to confirm, Is there only one marker! If there are multiple markers then you need to loop through.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Inside file hasil.xml there is 10 record. i have loop like this.
`for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
echo "<a href='javascript:Linkclicked(.$i.)'>try</a>"
}`

it couldn't displayed....